# Terraform OSS workspace scope and concurrency

Tags: terraform

I am using orchestration tools to automate Terraform deployments using the opensource version. I would like to know more on the workspace options that are available.

More specifically, what happens when two developers execute a Terraform deployment in two different workspaces at the same time using the same executable? The scope of the templates is within the directory however what will be the scope of the workspaces? Is the scope tied to a single Terraform executable or is it also directory driven?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, it's also directory driven. But you can configure different [backend types](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/index.html) (AWS S3, PostgreSQL, etc).

If you use AWS S3, each workspace will represent different files inside the bucket. If you use PostgreSQL, each workspace will represent a different row in the states table.

If two developers execute `terraform apply` for two different workspaces you won't have any problem, but you'll need [State locking](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/locking.html) to avoid two executions for the same workspace at the same time because this can potentially corrupt your state.

Comment: Thank you @pabloxio. This is exactly what I wanted to hear as concurrency is a must-have requirement for us; and yes I am using state lock via Azure storage account as backend.